# Shift manipulation in SQL to get counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net, case, common-table-expression

I have attendance in following table called `Attendance`

[image]

`EID` is employee ID and in shift column, `D` denotes a Day shift and `N` denotes a Night shift.

Now I'm trying to get following data pertaining to each employee.

No of Day shifts - count of `D`,
No of Night shifts - count of `N`,
No of Days worked - no of days an employee has worked either shift or both shifts (Even an employee worked both Day and Night on the same day its taken as one day.)

I can get all three information in three different results as follows...

```
WITH CTE (EID, in_time, shift) AS  
(
SELECT EID, in_time, shift FROM Attendance 
WHERE (in_time BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-07 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-07-31 00:00:00', 102)) AND PID = 'A002'
)

SELECT     EID, COUNT(*) AS DayTotal 
FROM         CTE
WHERE     (shift = 'D')
GROUP BY EID

SELECT     EID, COUNT(*) AS NightTotal 
FROM         Attendance
WHERE     (shift = 'N')
GROUP BY EID
;

WITH CTE2 (EID, in_time, shift) AS  
(
SELECT EID, in_time, shift FROM Attendance 
WHERE (in_time BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-07 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-07-31 00:00:00', 102)) AND PID = 'A002'
)
SELECT EID, COUNT ( DISTINCT CONVERT (DATE, in_time)) AS [Days] 
FROM CTE2 
WHERE (shift = 'D' OR shift = 'N')
GROUP BY EID
```

But I want to have this in single result (table). So I tried following query but it's not giving the intended output.

```
WITH CTE (EID, in_time, shift) AS  
(
SELECT EID, in_time, shift FROM Attendance 
WHERE (in_time BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-07 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-07-31 00:00:00', 102)) AND PID = 'A002'
)

SELECT EID, 
CASE WHEN Shift = 'D' THEN COUNT(Shift) END AS [Day],
CASE WHEN Shift = 'N' THEN COUNT(Shift) END AS [Night],   
COUNT ( DISTINCT CONVERT (DATE, in_time)) AS [Days]  
FROM         CTE 
GROUP BY EID, shift
```

Could you please let me know a way to do this?

The intended result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get what you want using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT EID,
       sum(case when shift = 'd' then 1 else 0 end) as dayshifts,
       sum(case when shift = 'n' then 1 else 0 end) as nightshifts,
       count(*) as total
FROM Attendance a
WHERE (in_time BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-07 00:00:00', 102) AND
                       CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-07-31 00:00:00', 102)) AND
      PID = 'A002';
```

EDIT:

If you want counts of distinct dates for the total, then use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT EID,
       sum(case when shift = 'd' then 1 else 0 end) as dayshifts,
       sum(case when shift = 'n' then 1 else 0 end) as nightshifts,
       count(distinct case when shift in ('d', 'n') then cast(in_time as date) end) as total
FROM Attendance a
WHERE (in_time BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-07 00:00:00', 102) AND
                       CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-07-31 00:00:00', 102)) AND
      PID = 'A002';
```

Comment: If someone works both the day and night shifts, wont they be counted twice in the 'Total' column?

Comment: Gidil is correct. It should not counted twice. Thanks

Comment: In line 4 first `cast` should be `case` instead. Now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte (eid, in_time, shift) 
     AS (SELECT eid, 
                in_time, 
                shift 
         FROM   attendance 
         WHERE  ( in_time BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-07 00:00:00', 102) 
                                  AND 
                                            CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                                            '2014-07-31 00:00:00', 
                                            102 
                                            ) ) 
                AND pid = 'A002') 

SELECT eid, 
       Sum(CASE 
               WHEN shift = 'D' THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
             END)                               AS DayTotal, 
       Sum(CASE 
               WHEN shift = 'N' THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
             END)                               AS NightTotal, 
       Count (DISTINCT CONVERT (DATE, in_time)) AS Days 
FROM   cte 
GROUP  BY eid
```

Comment: It works but there are mismatches in resulting figures. Mmm, values are not realistic but the conditions seems ok? I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: When count is used in this way it doesn't care about the condition and gives the count of both shifts. If sum was used instead, its giving the correct result. But I don't know the reason ;)

Answer (score 1):

@Chathuranga, Since Day and Night Shifts of a day should be counted as one, Please let me know if the below solution works for you.

```
DECLARE @Attendance TABLE (EID INT,
                      PID CHAR(4),
                      In_Time DATETIME,
                      Out_Time DATETIME,
                      Shift CHAR(1))

INSERT INTO @Attendance
VALUES
('100', 'A001', '2014-07-01 07:00:00.000', '2014-07-01 19:30:00.000', 'D'),
('102', 'A001', '2014-07-01 19:30:00.000', '2014-07-02 07:00:00.000', 'N'),
('100', 'A001', '2014-07-01 19:30:00.000', '2014-07-02 07:00:00.000', 'N'),
('104', 'A001', '2014-07-02 07:00:00.000', '2014-07-02 19:30:00.000', 'D'),
('100', 'A001', '2014-07-03 19:30:00.000', '2014-07-04 07:00:00.000', 'N'),
('102', 'A001', '2014-07-03 19:30:00.000', '2014-07-04 07:00:00.000', 'N'),
('104', 'A001', '2014-07-03 07:00:00.000', '2014-07-03 19:30:15.000', 'D'),
('102', 'A001', '2014-07-04 07:00:00.000', '2014-07-04 19:30:00.000', 'D'),
('100', 'A001', '2014-07-04 07:00:00.000', '2014-07-04 19:30:10.000', 'D')

SELECT EID,
      SUM(CASE
              WHEN Shift = 'D' THEN 1
              ELSE 0
          END) AS DayShift,
      SUM(CASE
              WHEN Shift = 'N' THEN 1
              ELSE 0
          END) AS NightShift,
      COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(In_Time AS DATE)) AS DayTotal
FROM @Attendance
GROUP BY EID
```